# Dependencies of dependencies not included in build output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, advantage-database-server

I have a C# solution in Visual Studio 2017. When I run it from my local machine, it works fine. However when I build the solution and move it to a new machine, it doesn't work because a dependency is missing.

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'ace32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I don't directly reference this DLL, but I've found that it's referenced in a direct dependency `Advantage.Data.Provider.dll`.

The `ace32.dll` dependency is included in the SDK for Advantage Database Server.

[image]

Do I need to install the SDK on the target machine? Or is there some way to include dependencies of this dependency so that `ace32.dll` is included in the Release build?

Comment: You should have a separate Visual Studio installer project (assuming you don't have one already) that will create something like a msi package containing all your dependencies. VS2015 comes with such a project to do this - for 2017 use this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Comment: The Advantage documentation tells you specifically which files must be redistributed with your application. Add those files to your installer. If you installed the help file, see the Contents tab under *Advantage .NET Data Provider*, specifically *Installation and Distribution*.

Comment: I've tried before to get access to the Advantage docs but get a server error every time I try to download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @auburg's comment I created an installer project and manually included `ace32.dll`. The error no longer occurs.